# Do authorization based on path variable in AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, authorization, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I have an AWS API Gateway which uses Cognito User Pool for authentication. I want to implement fine grained control for who can access which endpoints.

This is my requirement:

User making the request `charlie`:
/api/charlie/board/1   -> Allow

User making the request `daisy`:
/api/charlie/board/1   -> Deny

`charlie` and `daisy` here are the Cognito usernames (which I can extract from the JWT).

I am thinking of 2 ways to achieve this:

1. By writing a custom Lambda Authorizer (something like this: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/building-fine-grained-authorization-using-amazon-cognito-api-gateway-and-iam/).
2. My API Gateway is backed by Lambda function. Should I do this authorization in each of those lambda functions. I can extract the Cognito username from the Bearer token and the requested resource username from the path variable.

I'm leaning towards implementing #2. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

My advice would depend on the scale and complexity of the api. I think the main tradeoff is the maintainabiltiy of the authorization logic vs the added latency and complexity of having a lambda authorizer. And there is a small cost element attached to the tradeoff.

For relatively small api's, there is not much added value in centralizing the authorization logic. It will probably only be more complex to add lambda authorizers and you suffer from increased latencies. There are small other benefits like you dont pay the API GW cost for unauthorized requests, but often these are negligible.

For bigger APIs with complex auth logic it might make sense though. And even then it might be even better to include a shared library to all your backend lambdas.

So based on your post I'd recommend either creating a shared auth library and import them into your lambda functions.